# List all Profiles with access to a particular field

Tags: soql, profile, fields

Can I use SOQL to list all Profiles with a specific type of access to a standard field?  i.e. 'List all profile with Read-only access to the "Account Name" field on the Contact object'

What would that syntax be?

Comment: Checking only Profiles would not be appropriate since CRUD/FLS can be set through Permission Sets too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  This query lists all Profiles that have Edit access to the Contact.AccountId (Account Name) field:

```
SELECT Parent.Profile.Name, Parent.Label, Parent.IsOwnedByProfile, SobjectType, Field, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsRead 
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE SobjectType = 'Contact' AND Field = 'Contact.AccountId' AND PermissionsEdit = true
```

Comment: I get [object Object] in the Parent.Profile field instead of Name

Answer (score 3):

You can query the [`FieldPermissions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) object.

Example, to find all Profiles with Read-Only access to the "Account Name" field on Contact:

```sql
SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, ParentId, Parent.IsOwnedByProfile
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE SObjectType = 'Contact'
    AND Field = 'Contact.AccountId'
    AND Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = TRUE
    AND PermissionsEdit = FALSE
```

FieldPermissions are handled by PermissionSets *or* Profiles and using `Parent.IsOwnedByProfile` can help narrow that down. Similarly, if you want to see what field permissions a profile grants, see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71418/soql-statement-to-query-field-level-security-on-particular-profiles):

```sql
SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE parentId IN ( SELECT id 
                    FROM permissionset 
                    WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add the 'Profile NAME' to this query?   That's the part I'm struggling with.    Thanks!

Comment: Try adding `Parent.Profile.Name` to the `SELECT`. Technically the `Parent` is a PermissionSet, and if it's related to a Profile, then you need to make one more hop.