# Where can I set in Salesforce the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig fields that are accessible (or not) to my Profiles?

Tags: soql, metadata-api, metadata, fields, accessibilty

It's my first time dealing with PlatformEventSubscriberConfig in our project (and I'm very new to Salesforce, still a 6-month newbie).

We have 2 orgs and I noticed that when I query in UAT (Developer Console), I can freely access the fields and the query is successful. On the other hand, in PROD, I can only query** the fields Id, MasterLabel, and DeveloperName. I cannot query the fields like BatchSize, UserId, or PlatformEventConsumerId (they are not accessible).

**I used the query from [Tooling API Objects: PlatformEventSubscriberConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm).

```
SELECT Id, MasterLabel, DeveloperName, BatchSize, PlatformEventConsumerId, UserId FROM PlatformEventSubscriberConfig
```

I assumed that this is because of my different access/profiles in UAT and PROD. I went to Profiles > Profile Overview > Custom Metadata Types but the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig isn't there. And from [Metadata API: PlatformEventSubscriberConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm), it says that it's a component/metadata type and so it's not a custom object.

Where can I see the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig fields that are accessible (or not) to my profiles? Is there a similar "Field Accessibility" portion/area in Setup where I can set for PlatformEventSubscriberConfig fields?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any results when querying the FieldPermissions object as mentioned in [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343760/list-all-profiles-with-access-to-a-particular-field)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I tried to query it and got results. However, the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig and its fields are not there.

Answer (score 1):

I checked with the relevant salesforce product team on this. The fields PlatformEventConsumerId, UserId, BatchSize of PlatformEventSubscriberConfig
are guarded by the [Customize Application](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386451&type=1) permission based on internal Salesforce code.

You should be able to query the `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`'s complete fields if your profile has the Customize Application permission.